# Random characters getting printed in neovim buffer

Tags: character-encoding, neovim, terminator

I have recenty started to get a weird isssue with neovim where random characters get printed in my session. This can be replicated when I press `Space` in insert mode show below. These characters go away in normal mode. 
Also, after quitting from a session, there are some characters which get printed out on the terminal.

[image: Neovim-Session]

I am guessing that this issue is related with the character encoding, and the random characters are getting printed due to overflow, but am not sure.
**There seems to be no issue if I use some other terminal emulator** (I have tried this with gnome-terminal and everything seems to be working fine there).

Output of `locale` command in my system -

```
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
```

I am currently using [terminator](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Terminator) with the default encoding - `Unicode UTF-8`. My configuration file for terminator is available [here](https://github.com/shivrai/dotfiles/blob/master/terminator.conf).

I have tried changing encodings but it didn't seem to solve the issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. For the time being I have started using vim, the problem does not seem to be occurring there.

Comment: I actually ended up finding a solution in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131715/nvim-strange-character-after-pressing-enter)

Answer (score 1):

This helped my issue.

Hope this helps.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes

Comment: The FAQ entry is the correct answer, and should be posted here (without the "help!!!" and related discursions).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Neovim FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes):

> This is a bug in your terminal emulator. It happens because Nvim sends cursor-shape termcodes by default, if the terminal appears to be xterm-compatible (`TERM=xterm-256color`).
>
> To workaround the issue, you can:
>
> - Use a different terminal emulator
> - Disable `guicursor` in your Nvim config:
>
> ```
>   :set guicursor=
>   " Workaround some broken plugins which set guicursor indiscriminately.
>   :autocmd OptionSet guicursor noautocmd set guicursor=
> ```
>
> See also `:help $TERM` for recommended values of `$TERM`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the random characters were occurring because I installed the unstable version of neovim via `ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable` on **Ubuntu 16.10**.
The error went away on building the stable version `v0.1.7` from source.