# Nvim : Strange character after pressing enter

Tags: neovim

Using nvim 0.2.0-dev whenever i press enter or single quote strange symbol appears followed by 6q in the end of the line as shown in image below.

[nvim error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dLxk.png)

Comment: What are you asking here? You've just made a statement and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Better answer IMHO

add to init.vim

```
set guicursor=
```

That took care of my problem on nvim 0.2, see also the nvim wiki on cursor shape [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes).

Comment: This is the best answer for non-Ubuntu users and those who is not able to use the stable version.

Comment: See the Neovim FAQ for details: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#nvim-shows-weird-symbols-2-q-when-changing-modes

Comment: Yep prb w/ either people who do not read FAQ, late updated FAQ, or not easily searchable solution. Anyway, at least 2 people found my reply useful.
If FAQ was updated due to my solution, then even better. Nvim is my preferred editor & more people use it = better for all mankind.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by installing stable version of neovim

First removed unstable version

> sudo apt-get remove neovim

then removed repository

> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable

update repository

> sudo add-get update

Now added repository for stable version

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/stable

update repository

> sudo apt-get update

Installed stable neovim which is at this time 0.1.7

> sudo apt-get install neovim

Problem Solved

**Added Info** Dont know whether its necessary or not i also copied my init.vim file to safe location and deleted my nvim folder from ~/.config and after installing stable neovim created nvim folder inside ~./config and pasted my init.vim file there and installed my vim plugin manager following its guide and opened my nvim and ran my plugin install command everything is working exactly as it was earlier without that error